# How to create a "multi bit pin" for a schematic symbol in Eagle PCB?

Tags: eaglecad, bus

Here is the part for which I am making an Eagle part.

[image]

Now it is completely possible that I draw the schematic symbol looking like thie exactly. It is how I have seen things done often. However, I am curious to find out that is it possible that I have a single pin in the schematic symbol like R[0..7] which covers all R0,R1,R2... upto R7? And then this single multi bit pin in the schematic symbol shall map tp 8 pins in the package. Is it possible to do this in Eagle?

Comment: Look up "bus" in Eagle help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't assign multiple signals to one pin in Eagle, even if they have a common base name.  How would you be able to show the individual pin numbers on the part?

However to avoid clutter in a schematic, you can create **busses** as shown below:

[image]

In the Name dialog, the nets are separated by commas, in this case EN,VALVE[0..11].  But you still have to have an individual pin for each net.